# How to correctly use UnoCSS presets with Nuxt3?

Tags: css, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, daisyui, unocss

### Problem

I use Nuxt3 + UnoCSS + [DaisyUI community preset](https://github.com/kidonng/unocss-preset-daisy). When running `npx nuxi dev`, everything works well. However, when running `npx nuxi generate && npx serve dist`, UnoCSS works well but some of the DaisyUI preset styles are incorrect:

### Reproduce

I create a small online demo to illustrate this problem:

### https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-5h7iuh

This is in dev:

[image]

while this is in deployment:

[image]

### My try

I spent almost the whole day debugging but still did not find the reason... The only thing I found is that some styles in the daisyUI preset are not correct. Here's an example:

This is the styles of `btn-sm` class defined in `@kidonng/daisyui/utilities/styled/button.css`:

```css
.btn-sm {
    @apply h-8 px-3 min-h-8;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
  }
```

and this is what I see in chrome dev tool when running dev server (`h-8` means `height: 2rem`):

[image]

But this is what I see in chrome dev tool in deployment preview:

[image]

And this is the corresponding CSS file generated by Nuxt (`entry.7b197c61.css`):

```css
.btn-md,
.btn-sm {
  height: 3rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

The correct style should be `height: 2rem`, but the generated CSS is `height: 3rem`. This is really weird... I don't know what causes this and how to fix it. Hope someone may help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working daisyUI in dev & production https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gxjzue-1jzxtn

[image]

---

Seems to be related to how UnoCSS + cssnano interact.

`normalizeWhitespace` and `@apply` don't play well toghether:

https://github.com/unocss/unocss/discussions/2227#discussioncomment-5064858

```
cssnano: {
  preset: [
    'default',
    {
      mergeRules: false,
      normalizeWhitespace: false,
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Fix was released in version `@unocss/nuxt@0.49.8`